# How to rotate an image as it fades In and fades Out with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, rotation, jquery-animate

I believe this is pretty easy for you, as I have no idea how to integrate what I need into what I already have.

Please refer to this fiddle to see what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/pherrera/hnqfLvuk/1/

The code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

 var slowTwinkler = $('.slow');

 //play with the delay time to modify the twinkle order
 $('#star1').delay(5);

 function twinkleSlow() {
     slowTwinkler.animate({ opacity: '+=0.5'}, 1000);
     slowTwinkler.animate({ opacity: '=0.5' }, 3000);
     slowTwinkler.animate({ opacity: '-=0.8'}, 1000, twinkleSlow);
 }

 twinkleSlow();
});
```

As you can see it fadesIn and fadesOut as I want it, and I'd like to also rotate the image as it appears and disappears.

I found this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YKj5D/) where they use this function but I don't know hoe to add it to the code I have.
Rotating code:

```
var rotation = function () {
$("#image").rotate({
    angle: 0,
    animateTo: 360,
    callback: rotation
});
}
rotation();
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

     var slowTwinkler = $('.slow');

     //play with the delay time to modify the twinkle order
     $('#star1').delay(5);

 function twinkleSlow() {         
     slowTwinkler.animate({ opacity: '+=0.5' , deg: '+=180' }, {
         duration: 1000,
         step: function(now) {
             slowTwinkler.css({
                 '-moz-transform': 'rotate('+now+'deg)',
                 '-webkit-transform': 'rotate('+now+'deg)',
                 '-o-transform': 'rotate('+now+'deg)',
                 '-ms-transform': 'rotate('+now+'deg)',
                 transform: 'rotate('+now+'deg)'
             });
         }
     });
     slowTwinkler.animate({ opacity: '=0.5' }, 3000);
     slowTwinkler.animate({ opacity: '-=0.8', deg: '+=180' }, {
         duration: 1000,
         step: function(now) {
             slowTwinkler.css({
                 '-moz-transform': 'rotate('+now+'deg)',
                 '-webkit-transform': 'rotate('+now+'deg)',
                 '-o-transform': 'rotate('+now+'deg)',
                 '-ms-transform': 'rotate('+now+'deg)',
                 transform: 'rotate('+now+'deg)'
             });
         },
         complete: twinkleSlow
     });
 }

     twinkleSlow();
 });
```

Link to jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hnqfLvuk/4/).

Comment: Thanks, I had to duplicate part of the code for it to work when appearing and also when disappearing.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 var slowTwinkler = $('.slow');
 //play with the delay time to modify the twinkle order
 $('#star1').delay(5);
 function twinkleSlow() {
     slowTwinkler.animate({ opacity: '+=0.5'}, 1000);
     slowTwinkler.animate({ opacity: '=0.5' }, 3000);
     slowTwinkler.animate({ opacity: '-=0.8'}, 1000, twinkleSlow);
 }

 function rotation () {
     slowTwinkler.animate({ rotation: '+=360'}, 1000);
     slowTwinkler.animate({ opacity: '=180' }, 3000);
 }
 rotation();
 twinkleSlow();
});
```

I am not a super expert on JavaScript (so you may need to try some variants) but the above could maybe work?